# Can I set conditions for how values display?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm not sure if this is the best way to ask the question, but I can't think of a better one.  I am new to Crystal Reports and have been basically left to figure it out on my own with just some resource books and YouTube.

My issue is this: I am building a report for a school that displays the next year's course selections.  The report is pulling the values from an online form the students fill out and displays results on the report with two names, let's call them "report.name" and "report.value".  "report.name" is an arbitrary value that the HTML of the form uses.  I am wondering if it's possible to give Crystal a set of conditions so that I can format the way it displays to be a little cleaner.

Example:

```
CurrentMathClass         Geometry
NextYearsMathClass       Algebra 2
ElectiveChoice1-Grade10  Spanish 1
```

Right now the report is showing it like this because those are the values it is seeing.  I would like it to be like this:

```
Current Math Class      Geometry
Next Year's Math Class  Algebra 2
Elective Choice 1       Spanish 1
```

Is there a way to give CR a set of conditions that tells it to print something different when it sees specific values, without removing the 'Name' field from the report?

Sorry if this questions is all over the place, I'm having a tough time organizing my thoughts.  I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: Use a formula instead of the field.  If field = x then y.

Comment: Where do I place that formula?  In the Record Selection formula field?  I tried adding one like so:

if {report.name} = "CurrentMathClass" then PRINT "Current Math Class"

It returned an error.

Comment: Record selection is for selecting records. That isn't your problem.  Look to the right of Crystal. You'll see "Formula Fields".  create a new formula.  Call it @namechange or something.  If {report.name} = "CurrentMathClass" Then "Current Math Class".  No PRINT needed.  Drag that formula object onto the report.

Answer (score 0):

Look to the right of Crystal. You'll see "Formula Fields".

Create a new formula. Call it @namechange or something.

If {report.name} = "CurrentMathClass" Then "Current Math Class".

Drag that formula object onto the report.